# Redirecting a form to another form dynamically

Tags: django, forms, url, redirect, render

I'm a beginner in Django. So I do sincerely apologize in advance if my question is dummy. That being said, I've been trying to search for the answer on the Internet for days with no success so far.

In a nutshell, I have a form made of a single **MultipleChoiceField**.

When the user connects for the 1st time on the webpage with this form, he can check the boxes which are appropiate and then hit a Submit button. So far, I manage to do it.

Where I get stuck is on how to redirect the user to another form (in total there will be 10 forms, until he reaches a "complete" webpage).

Using **redirect**, I know how to redirect the user to a static webpage, but I could not figure out how to redirect him to a dynamic webpage (ie based on the variables values within my view).

Below are the scripts I wrote to give you a better idea of what I'm trying to achieve:

**[views.py]**

```
def my_form(request, id):

    form = MyForm(request.POST or None, form_id=id)

    if form.is_valid():

        # DO SOME CLEAN-UP...

        form.id += 1
        id += 1

    return render(request, 'my_form.html', {'form': form, 'id': id})
```

**[urls.py]**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
] +
[url('my_form', views.my_form, {'id': 1}, name='my_form'))]
```

As you can imagine, my aim was to start with id 1, and then everytime the user clicks the Submit button, he gets redirected to the id + 1 form until number 10.

With the above code, I always get redirected to page with id = 1.

There must be something I did not understand in request usage, but I cannot figure out what. And the many questions I red on this board and others did not help.

I would be more than happy to ear about where I went wrong from those of you with more Django experience than me.

Thank you very much in advance.
Sophie :)

**[EDIT 06/10/2018]**

The code looks as per the below now:

**[my_form.html]**

```
<form action="{% url 'my_form' %}" method="post">



    {% csrf_token %}

    <table border="1">
        {{ form.as_p }}
    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>

</form>
```

**[urls.py]**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
] +
[path('question/<int:id>/', views.my_form, name="my_form")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [HttpResponseRedirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/http/response/#HttpResponseRedirect) help you.

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('my_form', kwargs={'id':id})
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems I'm making progress with your comment. Using the above and the tutorial I found on the Internet for reverse, I'm now stuck with a NoReverseMatch namespace error. The few places I could think of where I might do something wrong is in **my_form.html** where I have

`<form action="{% url 'quizz' %}" method="post">`

and in **urls.py** where I have

`path('question/<int:id>/', views.my_form, name="my_form")`

I suspect the error is in the action of the form where I should somehow put the id, but I did not manage to find out how.

Comment: It seems I'm doing an infinite loop with your change. Would you have any idea what's causing it?